# Python script to call functions in it

Tags: python, argparse

I have a bunch of related functions defined in a .py file, and would like to call those at terminal using a python script. I tried something like this:

```
def func1(a, b, c):
    """ docstring for func1 """
    some codes

def func2(a, b):
    """ docstring for func2 """
    some codes

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
suparsers = parser.add_subparsers
parser_func1 = suparser.add_parser(func1, description=func1.__doc__)
parser_func1.set_defaults(func=func1)
...

parser.add_argument('args', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(*args.args)
```

While it works if I know all the arguments needed for `funcs` or my `docstring` has explanation for all the arguments, sometimes just the definition itself is obvious (like those that appears in ipython).

However, to get that kind of 'help' for each subcommands, I would have to duplicate all the arguments using `add_argument`  with `help=` keyword to each of the parsers..

Is there a generic, compact way to write a script to execute a number of functions as subcommands, and use `docstring/definition` of these functions as help with minimal duplication?

Comment: `plac` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac uses `inspect` to get more information about function arguments .  It uses that info to construct an `argparse` `parser` that can call that function.  In Python3 it can make use of `function annotations`.  It may meet your needs, or may just give ideas of how to write your own tool.